# WordPress - Sanitize user input params in REST api request

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created some custom rest routes using wp `register_rest_route()` function.
All the routes works fine, but I need to sanitize the inputs that will be passed to other wp functions and will create an user. I've read about `map_deep()` function, but when I need to use the `wp_insert_user()` or `wp_update_user()` I will have nested array for user meta and user basic info like email etc, and I need to apply `sanitize_email` or other sanitization functions.

Will the sanitize functions wirk if I call them directly inside the defined array that will be passed to `wp_insert_user()` or `wp_update_user()` functions?

```php
<?php
//example
wp_insert_user(
 'user_email' => sanitize_email( $request->get_param('email') ),
 'meta_input' => array(
  'gamer_tag' => sanitize_text_field( $request->get_param('gamer_tag') )
 )
);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sanitizing functions will work in your code snippet.

**NOTE: There is an issue in your code snippet, you're not passing `array` or `object` you're directly writing array keys and values, you need to wrap the keys within an array**

The correct code is here:

```
<?php
wp_insert_user(
    array( // You were missing this array wrap
        'user_email' => sanitize_email( $request->get_param( 'email' ) ),
        'meta_input' => array(
            'gamer_tag' => sanitize_text_field( $request->get_param( 'gamer_tag' ) ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake I've made to show the example. At this point I think I will use the sanitize directly in the params when I'm adding them as key value instead of using `map_deep()`

Comment: `map_deep` will be helpful only if you have to apply the same sanitize for all the fields. here you need email sanitize and text sanitize so `map_deep` will be good only for `meta_input` if all the meta need text sanitization only.